# Clustering data based on distance

Tags: javascript, cluster-analysis

Let this array be my dataset:

```
[
{"x": 0, "y": 13},
{"x": 23, "y": 42},
{"x": 5, "y": 129},
{"x": 589, "y": 750},
{"x": 600, "y": 600},
// ...
]
```

---

I'm looking to group items(by providing as an argument the number of groups I want to build) based on:

- distance between them while *preserving* their z-order in the dataset.

This looks straightforward to do, since I can just *exhaustively search all* items and link them using the *distance-formula* but that would make it terribly inefficient and naive.

I'm figuring this is a classroom example of the optimization problem, with some already defined algorithms to solve efficiently.

What's the "standard" for attacking this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you're looking for is probably the [k-means clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)

[Here](https://github.com/NathanEpstein/clusters) is a javascript implementation you may use. [Many others](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=javascript%20k-means&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults) exist.

Comment: Confused this with the k nearest-neighbour instead. That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks.